# How to turn sqlalchemy logging off completely

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy, python-logging

sqlalchemy is keep loggin to console even I have the following code

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.disabled = True
```

How to turn off sqlalchemy's logging completely?

Comment: Can you post your engine configuration and logging configuration?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Did you pass `echo=True` to `create_engine()`? By default it creates StreamHandler which outputs to console. As [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) says, if you didn't provide any `echo=True` arguments and didn't configure root `sqlalchemy` logger, it will not log anything.

Comment: or it can be `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` env var in flask config

Answer (score 13):

You can turn off the `sqlalchemy` logger using:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

For more info, see the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging).

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Setting logging verbosity at the config level is much better practice than having to pass the `echo=False` to all functions that may ever create an engine.

Comment: For me I downvoted because I tried this technique and it didn't worked.

Comment: Changed the anser from `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')` to `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')`, which should cover more cases. Other than that, don't know why it wouldn't work...

Comment: Thank you for updating the code, but on my end it still doesn't work. Here's the error: `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:450: Warning: Duplicate entry 'some-key-duplicate' for key 'title'
  cursor.execute(statement, parameters)`

Comment: @CyrilN. this does not look like it's related to logging. There is probably an error in your `statement` query. Maybe you're trying to insert into the same column multiple times or something..

Comment: The warning are because I'm trying to insert an entry that fails because of unique constraints. The query contains an "INSERT IGNORE" so it works nonetheless (no entries are added), but so should not display a warning. My issue here is that in the end, SQLAlchemy show me a warning I'd like to silent, which is the subject of this question.

Comment: I've removed my downvote since your answer works in general (tried to change to debug and got more details). But I don't know why the warning keeps printing.

Comment: @ostrokach - Even after setting the log level for sqlalchemy I have detailed SQL output plus these startup messages: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
SELECT VERSION()
SELECT DATABASE()
SELECT @@tx_isolation
show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'

Comment: I also downvoted. While this *should* work, SQL alchemy goes to some length to bypass this. Contrary to all common sense and best practices.

Comment: Logging and Warnings are different systems in Python, consult the docs.

Answer (score 3):

A more drastic solution:

```
import logging

logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Tried everything above, this is the only thing that worked with INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine logging. 

```logging.disable(logging.INFO)```

Comment: This worked for me. I added it to the top of my flask's `app.py` file.