# How to suppress extremely long sqlalchemy errors?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have `echo` set to `False` as suggested in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901825/6253539), but I still get a log that looks like:

```
| CRITICAL | (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
[SQL: INSERT INTO <EXTREMELY long log here showing a massive insert>
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Is there a way to suppress this? I'm inserting a huge chunk of data, and errors like this blow up my logs.

Comment: It cannot be a good idea to suppress critical errors. I would suggest you to fix the root cause instead.

Comment: Right- the error message is extremely long and therefore clogs up my logs and makes it harder to read. Instead, I want to handle this error on my own and print out a shorter error message that doesn't show all the contents of this massive insert.