# Completely disabling logs from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

I am trying to turn logging off from sqlalchemy completely. I am creating a custom logging framework for Flask and errors from sqlalchemy/engine/base.py, sqlalchemy/engine/impl.py keep showing up..
I tried doing: `logging.getLogger('SQLAlchemy.pool.base').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())`
and
`logging.getLogger('SQLAlchemy.pool.impl').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())`

but they didn't work because they don't leverage python logging traditionally. Instead of having `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)` they import from a log file in the library and so I then tried:

`logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.log').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())` instead, but that didn't work either.

I tried the following, but those didn't pan out either:

[How to turn sqlalchemy logging off completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900888/how-to-turn-sqlalchemy-logging-off-completely)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#more-on-the-echo-flag

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    engine = create_engine('snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'.format(user='user-name', password='password', account='account'), echo=False, echo_pool=False)

    try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        results = connection.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
        print(results[0])
        connection.close()
    finally:
        engine.dispose()

    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

and here is the errors:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 606, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
TypeError: debug() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_projects/app.py", line 69, in home
    connection = engine.connect()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3165, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3244, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3211, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 84, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(value, with_traceback=traceback)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
TypeError: debug() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "sample_projects/app.py", line 76, in home
    engine.dispose()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2920, in dispose
    self.pool.dispose()
  File "sample_projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 195, in dispose
    self.logger.info("Pool disposed. %s", self.status())
TypeError: info() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I would appreciate any insight that you might have. Ask me questions if I forgot to address something. Thank you if you read this far haha!

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't work because you're adding a handler on top of the existing handlers.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())  # creates an additional log handler
```

What you actually want to do is modify the existing handler.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  # modifies the current log handler
```

Comment: It's still not working for me. I am still getting the same errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the handlers with the NullHandler:

```py
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy").handlers = [logging.NullHandler()]
```